# Unable to fully specialize template for string literals

Tags: c++

I'm creating my own `lexical_cast` functions to wrap Boost's, with special behavior for `bool` types, and also to avoid exception-versions of Boost's lexical cast functions.

I'm fully specializing the functions for `bool` so that I can use iostreams for the `std::boolalpha` manipulator. However, I can't get it working for string literals. The full code is below, along with a link to a live sample:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 lexical_cast(T2 const& value, T1 const& defaultValue = T1{})
{
    std::cout << "Generic Conversion\n";
    T1 convertedValue;
    if (!boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert(value, convertedValue))
    {
       return defaultValue;
    }

    return convertedValue;
}

template<>
bool lexical_cast<bool, char const*>(char const* const& value, bool const& defaultValue)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized c string to bool\n";
    bool convertedValue;
    std::istringstream ss(value);
    if (!(ss >> std::boolalpha >> convertedValue))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed string to bool\n";
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return convertedValue;
}

template<>
bool lexical_cast<bool, std::string>(std::string const& value, bool const& defaultValue)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized string to bool\n";
    return lexical_cast<bool>(value.c_str(), defaultValue);
}

template<>
std::string lexical_cast<std::string, bool>(bool const& value, std::string const& defaultValue)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized bool to string\n";
    std::ostringstream ss;
    if (!(ss << std::boolalpha << value))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed bool to string\n";
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    lexical_cast<std::string>(3.14f);
    lexical_cast<float>("3.14");
    lexical_cast<int>("3.14");
    lexical_cast<bool>("true");
    lexical_cast<std::string>(true);
}
```

[Live Sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O7VzEZiUWAQw7wl3)

The code above gives me the output:

```
Generic Conversion
Generic Conversion
Generic Conversion
Generic Conversion
Specialized bool to string
```

The 4th case in the tests in `main` above should not be "generic conversion", it should be using the C-string specialization.

I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole of template nastiness here, and the solution is quickly becoming confusing & complex for something so seemingly simple. What is the ideal solution for what I'm trying to do? How do I get bool specialization working as I want?

## EDIT

Clarification on requirements: I understand that string literals are actually arrays of characters. In my example above, I tried with `char*` anyway since accepting an array of char requires another non-type template argument, which I knew right away I couldn't consume since it would require partially specializing my function template, which is illegal.

Secondly, I realize overloads could also be used but I cannot allow cases where `lexical_cast` can be used without specifying the template parameter for the return type. For example, I have to do `lexical_cast<bool>("true")`, I can't do `lexical_cast("true")`. My goal is to remain interface-compatible with `boost::lexical_cast`, which does not have cases where the template argument can be omitted.

Because I have to use the template syntax when I invoke `lexical_cast`, I feel like I'm forced to use full function specializations.

Comment: The type of a c-string literal is `const char[]` see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: What is a reason to pass char pointer and bool by reference?

Comment: FWIW, normally you can solve most of your problems by adding overloads instead of specializations.  Overloads allow conversions/decay to happen where specializations do not.

Comment: @Slava because I'm fully specializing a function template, I have to keep the CV qualifications otherwise the compiler complains that it's not actually specializing anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not using overloads here because then I can't do `lexical_cast<bool>()`. To use the template syntax I have to specialize.

Comment: @void.pointer - Template functions can be overloaded with other template functions too.

Comment: @StoryTeller Do you have an example? How would the compiler know it's an overload versus some partial specialization? Also how do you make the template overloads non-ambiguous without type traits? I don't see how you'd do that in my particular example.

Comment: @void.pointer I don't get it.  Why can't you just add `template<size_t N>
bool lexical_cast(const char (&value)[N], bool const& defaultValue)`?

Comment: Because then I can't do `lexical_cast<bool>("foo")`, I have to do `lexical_cast("foo")`. The interface is inconsistent, where in other similar cases I'd need to explicitly specify the return type as a template argument, such as `lexical_cast<float>("123.4")`. The goal is for the interface to be interchangeable with `boost::lexical_cast`, which does not have special cases where you can omit the explicit template argument.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Let me think on that.

Comment: Here's your example ([link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a2cee37bbb7ffdc)). As for all the how questions, I'm afraid a comment is a bit too narrow a canvas.

Comment: @void.pointer: You're looking for `template<typename T1, size_t N> T1 lexical_cast(const char (&value)[N], T1 defaultValue = T!{})` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's investigations here, it sparked some ideas of my own and I think I found a satisfactory solution. The key is to use template overrides, which was a hint from someone else in this thread. Thanks to everyone for the help. Here's the solution:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 lexical_cast(T2 const& value, T1 const& defaultValue = T1{})
{
    std::cout << "Generic Conversion\n";
    T1 convertedValue;
    if (!boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert(value, convertedValue))
    {
       return defaultValue;
    }

    return convertedValue;
}

template<>
std::string lexical_cast<std::string, bool>(bool const& value, std::string const& defaultValue)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized bool to string\n";
    std::ostringstream ss;
    if (!(ss << std::boolalpha << value))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed bool to string\n";
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return ss.str();
}

template<typename B>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<B, bool>::value, B>
lexical_cast(char const* value, bool defaultValue = {})
{
    std::cout << "Specialized c string to bool\n";
    bool convertedValue;
    std::istringstream ss(value);
    if (!(ss >> std::boolalpha >> convertedValue))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed string to bool\n";
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return convertedValue;
}

template<typename B>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<B, bool>::value, B>
lexical_cast(std::string const& value, bool defaultValue = {})
{
    std::cout << "Specialized string to bool\n";
    return lexical_cast<bool>(value.c_str(), defaultValue);
}

template<typename T>
void PrintResult(T const& result)
{
    std::cout << "--- Result: " << result << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    PrintResult(lexical_cast<std::string>(3.14f));
    PrintResult(lexical_cast<float>("3.14"));
    PrintResult(lexical_cast<int>("3.14"));
    PrintResult(lexical_cast<bool>("true"));
    PrintResult(lexical_cast<std::string>(true));

    std::string trueString = "true";
    PrintResult(lexical_cast<bool>(trueString));
}
```

The output:

```
Generic Conversion
--- Result: 3.1400001
Generic Conversion
--- Result: 3.14
Generic Conversion
--- Result: 0
Specialized c string to bool
--- Result: 1
Specialized bool to string
--- Result: true
Specialized string to bool
Specialized c string to bool
--- Result: 1
```

And the [live sample here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LzoYcKis4wsvGz8T).

Answer (score 4):

You have to remember that string literals are really *arrays* of `const` characters.

The correct way to have a function accept string literals is like this:

```
template<size_t N>
void function(char const (&string)[N]);
```

Don't forget that the size `N` includes the null-terminator.

Comment: Another thing to remember that this isn't a specialization for string literals only, but for all arrays of `const char`. As such, the array - if it isn't a string literal - might contain a null terminated string that is much shorter than `N`, or it might not be null terminated at all. Anecdote: I stumbled upon a logging library that had UB when the message was a character array which contained a shorter string, than the full array.

Comment: But I can't partially specialize the template function to add the non-type template parameter, right? That's why I didn't bother with the char-array. Can you please confirm your solution works in my live sample? I know I'm asking a lot but it will help the struggle I'm having...

Comment: @void.pointer That's true. And since you don't want to use overloading I really don't know what to do. Have Boost `lexical_cast` solved it? Can you look at how they handle it? (And if you figure it out yourself, don't be shy to answer your own question!)

Comment: @void.pointer: Partial specialization is allowed only for classes, precisely because you cannot overload classes. This was a conscious decision.